# Singular points of $\alpha(t)=(t^2\cos(t),t^2\sin(t))$

Tags: curves

I have to find the singular points of
$$\alpha(t)=(t^2\cos(t),t^2\sin(t))$$
with $-2\pi\leq t\leq2\pi$. Its first derivative is
$$\alpha'(t)=(2t\cos(t)-t^2\sin(t),2t\sin(t)+t^2\cos(t))$$
and so $t$ is singular if $\alpha'(t)=0$:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}2t\cos(t)-t^2\sin(t)=0 \\ 2t\cos(t)+t^2\sin(t)=0 \end{array}\right.$$
which clearly show
$$t=0$$
is a singular point.
But, my question is: in both equations, when I factor them, I got
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}2\cos(t)-t\sin(t)=0 \\ 2\cos(t)+t\sin(t)=0 \end{array}\right.$$
and so
$$\cos(t)=\frac{t\sin(t)}{2}$$
and then, putting it in the second equation:
$$2\sin(t)+\frac{t^{2}\sin(t)}{2}=0\Rightarrow\sin(t)(4+t^2)=0$$
therefore
$$\sin(t)=0\Rightarrow t=n\pi$$
But I know that the only singular point is $t=0$. What is wrong here?

Comment: Check your derivatives.  First you have $\frac{d}{dt} t^{2}\sin(t) =2t\cos(t)+t^2\cos(t)$ and then you have $2t\cos(t)+t^2\sin(t)$ instead, when it should have been $2t\sin(t) + t^2\cos(t)$ in the first place.

Comment: Yes, they are wrong, but still, the system below is correct.

Comment: You still have $2t\cos(t)+t^2\sin(t)$ in the system instead of $2t\sin(t) + t^2\cos(t)$.  The first gives you $2\cos(t) + t\sin(t)$ when you divide by $t$, but the second gives you $2\sin(t) + t\cos(t)$, and those two are not equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have noted that your derivatives are incorrect. They should be the ones below, which is what I will work with.
$$
\begin{cases}
2t\cos(t) - t^2\sin(t)=0 \\ 
2t\sin(t) + t^2\cos(t)=0 
\end{cases}
$$
The first equation is $t(2\cos t - t \sin t)=0$, which implies that either $t=0$ or $2\cos t = t \sin t$. Notice $t=0$ works in the second equation so that $t=0$ is a singular point. Now let's assume that $2 \cos t= t \sin t$. From the second equation, we have $t(2 \sin t + t \cos t)=0$, so either $t=0$ (which we already know is a solution) or $2 \sin t= -t \cos t$. But we know that $2 \cos t = t \sin t$, so that
$$
4 \cos t= 2 \cdot 2\cos t= 2 \cdot t \sin t= t \cdot 2\sin t= -t^2 \cos t
$$
Then we know $t^2 \cos t + 4 \cos t= 0$. This is the same as $\cos t (t^2+4)=0$. Clearly, $t^2+4= 0$ produces no solution so that it must be that $\cos t= 0$. Since you are on $-2\pi \leq t \leq 2\pi$, this means $t= \pm \dfrac{\pi}{2}$. Checking, however, we see that these are extraneous solutions as they satisfy neither equation. Therefore, we are only left with the solution $t=0$.